# Proof that the order of any finite $p$-group is a power of $p$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups

What is the most concise proof that the order of any finite $p$-group is a power of $p$?

Comment: what is your definition of $p$-group?

Comment: I am using the definition that a finite group is a p-group if the order of every element is a power of p. (I'm assuming the group is finite.)

Answer (score 13):

Certainly the [Theorem of Cauchy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy%27s_theorem_%28group_theory%29) would do it - if $q$ is a prime other than $p$, dividing the order of $G$, then there would be an element of order $q$, a contradiction.

Comment: But how do we know the order of the p-group is not n times a power of p?

Comment: Or, for that matter, any prime number or power thereof?

Comment: @user180301 This answer shows that $|G|$ can have no prime factors other than $p$, which is the same as saying that it's a $p$-th power.

Answer (score 1):

Given $p$-group $G$ , its order is not a power of $p$, then there is a prime $q$ that devides $|G|$.

Quote: Sylow’s Theorem -- Given $G$ a finite group such that $q^n$ divides $|G|$, where $q$ is prime. Then there exists a subgroup of order $q^n$.

So $G$ has a subgroup $H$ of order $q$. As $q$ is prime, $H$ is a cyclic group, and its members, which are also $G$'s members, have order $q$. This conflicts with the $p$-group definition.

Comment: Seems a bit of a stretch to invoke Sylow in a “concise proof” if all you need is Cauchy... which is usually needed to prove Sylow in the first place, especially to prove that $G$ has a subgroup of order $q$. Sure, the H-bomb will kill the fly, but you’re better off using the fly-swatter....

Comment: @ArturoMagidin i'm self-studying reading https://math.berkeley.edu/~apaulin/AbstractAlgebra.pdf which contains only Sylow ... thx for the tip, let me digest Cauchy..

Answer (score 0):

From Lagrange's theorem we know only that |G| can be divided by the order of the elements. So, for example, |G| = n * p^k ,where n is an integer not equal to p, and p^k is the order of some element.
By Cauchy's Theorem then, there will be an element of order p.  As Hekster notes above, this implies that there cannot be a different prime factor q of |G|, because that would lead to a violation of the p-group assumption.
Also, if |G| = n * p^k, where n is not a prime or equal to 1, there is a contradiction since n can be written as the product of primes.

Comment: If you are going to invoke Cauchy’s Theorem, then there is absolutely no need to talk about Lagrange’s Theorem.